# Matplotlib: Making a line graph's datetime x axis labels look like Excel

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple pandas DataFrame with yearly values that I am plotting as a line graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

>>>df
            a   b
2010-01-01  9.7 9.0
2011-01-01  8.8 14.2
2012-01-01  8.4 7.6
2013-01-01  9.6 8.4
2014-01-01  8.2 5.5
```

The expected format for the X axis is to use no margins for the labels:

```
fig  = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
df.plot(ax = ax)
```

[image: matplotlib figure]

But I would like to force the values to plot in the middle of the year range, like as done in excel:

[image: excel figure]

I have tried setting the x axis margins:

```
ax.margins(xmargin = 1)
```

But can see no difference.

Comment: It's kind of weird to use a day-specific date in the XL example for a year-sized region. Or, it's odd to use only the year in the matplotlib example.  (Either could be an immovable cultural norm, but they're not consistent with the rest of the plot metric.)

Comment: Can you clarify this?  Not really sure what you mean.

Comment: The mpl xlabels describe a whole year, but are aligned with a tick that points to a specific day. The excel labels specify a day, but are aligned in the middle of the whole year (I assume the ticks are the year boundaries, so the excel labels are carefully not under the point that they describe.)

Comment: Ah ok, so this behavior in matplotlib is because of the day of the year?

Comment: Possibly. Some combination of the datetime objects being day-specific, and the default tick choices in matplotlib or in pandas. I'm not really talking about *how* to move ticklabels, though, I'm talking about how to make the meaning consistent with the physical metaphor of the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to move the dates, you could try adding this line at the end:

```
ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[0] - 0.5, ax.get_xlim()[1] + 0.5)
```

If you need to format the dates as well you could either modify your index or make changes in the plotted ticks like so:
(presuming that you `df.index` is a `datetime` object)

```
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')))
```

This will format the dates to look like your Excel example.

Or you could change your `index` to look like you want and then call `.plot()`:

```
df.index = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
print df.index.tolist()

['01/01/2010', '01/01/2011', '01/01/2012', '01/01/2013', '01/01/2014']
```

And, if you `index` is not `datetime` you need to convert it first like this:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Comment: First solution is easy enough for me.